# Add customized attribute to <c:out> tag in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I'm new to JSP, so I have a problem when using  JSP tag to display some messages.
I want to display those messages follow this convention: **if text's length equals or less than 50, then it will show the whole text content, otherwise just display first 50 characters and append the "..." to its tail.**
I'm thinking about the solution of adding one more attribute (called maxDisplayChars, with type is integer) to do this. If this attribute is specified, then the display convention will be executed, if not then the default behavior of  will be kept as default. This additional attribute will help me to reduce code changes, just review which part of application need to be applied this rule and "plug" this attribute in.
Do you think this solution is possible? If YES, so how to implement it (sorry, I'm just a novice in JSP and JSTL -_-), and if NO is there any alternative way to overcome this problem?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have three reasonable options:

**1.** Shorten using a JSP custom tag ([brief intro](http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/jserverpages3_ch11/index.html))
**2.** Shorten the data before it gets to your JSP
**3.** Do it on the client side using JavaScript, for example, using [jQuery truncator](http://renderedtext.com/blog/2010/05/19/smartly-truncate-long-text-and-markup-with-jquery.truncator/)

Each has advantages and disadvantages.

---

**Custom tag**

(Could be in Java, too, but ew.) Easy to implement, allows picking sizes using a parameter from the JSP, can include whatever options you want, including related to JS (see #3).

**Shorten before JSP**

The biggest drawback is that you're picking the length in your back-end code, and a change means re-compiling and deploying. For example, you could just chop the text to 40 chars.

**Use JavaScript**

The most flexible. Might not be optimal if you're shrinking gigantic strings, in which case I'd consider a combination of a custom tag and JS.

Nice part is that you can do things like put the rest of the text (the truncated part) into a hover-triggered popup and stuff like that using somebody else's code. You could use the same JS in a custom tag as well, leading to a pretty robust solution.